# How to easily identify which nodes have logic bricks attached to them in the outliner

Tags: interface

I downloaded an .blend file that has a lot of objects listed in the outliner, I wonder how can I find which nodes have logic bricks attached, because in the logic editor there seems to be no way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following in the [Text Editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Text_editor) to select all objects in the scene with a logicbrick.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
logicbricks = ("controllers", "sensors", "actuators")
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if any(len(getattr(obj.game, brick_type)) for brick_type in logicbricks):
        obj.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
```

Comment: Cool! using your script and showing only the selected objects in the outliner is that I wanted